# order random effects plot by size of parameter estimates (using nlme)

Tags: r, nlme

I want to make a random effects plot using the plot method for `ranef` objects (`plot.ranef.lme`).

```
library(nlme)

x <- Orthodont
# change factor to unordered for this example
x$Subject <- factor(x$Subject, ordered=FALSE)   

m <- lme(distance ~ age, x, random = ~ 1 | Subject)
re <- ranef(m)
plot(re)
```

[image]

Above, the order of the factor on the y-axis follows the order of the factor levels.
Now, I want the order of the levels to correspond to the size of the random effect parameters. The best I could come up with is to reorder the factor levels by using the random effects parameters **after** estimating the model, reorder the factor and estimate the model again. This is clumsy to say the least, but I was unable to get this done via some arguments in  the plot method (I am not very familiar with lattice).

```
o <- order(re[, 1])
x$Subject <- factor(x$Subject, levels=levels(x$Subject)[o])
m <- lme(distance ~ age, x, random = ~ 1 | Subject)
re <- ranef(m)
plot(re)
```

[image]

This is what I want but without using the clumsy approach above.
How can I do this in a more sensible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think teher is a parameter that can be used to change order levels. You should do it by hand .

That's said you can plot your own `dotplot` using the `re` object, and use `reorder` to order factor.

```
 library(lattice)
 dat = data.frame(x= row.names(re),y=re[,attr(re,'effectName')])
 dotplot(reorder(x,y)~y,data=dat)
```